# Promise call gets invoked twice in Angular 11

Tags: promise, es6-promise, angular-promise

I have below code which invokes a service to get some values, I knowingly shut down the backend part to check if error is being added. I noticed it makes the service call twice, can someone explain me why this is happening?

```
(async () => {
      try {
        this.countries = await this.testerSvc.getCountries().toPromise();
      } catch (err) {
        this.addError("Countries");
      }
    })();
```

**Service code:**

```
getCountries() {
    return this.http.get<[]>(this.baseUrl + "countries");
}
```

Comment: Where exactly did you put the code from your first snippet?

Comment: @Bergi That's inside my component's constructor.

Comment: So something is instantiating that component twice. However, I would recommend to avoid putting asynchronous side effects in a constructor.

Comment: Found my issue. I had added my component in app.module.ts's bootstrap section:  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MyComponent]. I removed from there and now it's making the service call only once. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my app.module.ts I had added my component:

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent, MyComponent]
```

On my app.component.html, I had

```
<app-tester> </app-tester>
```

It was instantiating my component twice, I removed from the bootstrap and now it's instantiating only once. So service call is only once.